# Firebug command editor disabled

Tags: javascript, editor, firebug

The command editor on the console tab is simply disabled.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF9mR.png

I have reset all the settings and it still does not recover itself.
Also I have enabled all the panels.
What can I do to re-enable it?

Comment: click on the bug icon above the bookmark tool-bar...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug!#Isolating_the_problem) are some steps to isolating the Firebug problem:

1. Create a new profile, install Firebug, reproduce the problem. Still a bug? Report the problem, else
2. Return to your previous profile, open the Add-ons Manager via Firefox menu bar > Tools > Add-ons, Firefox button > Add-ons or about:addons to disable all extensions except Firebug. Solved? Enable the other extensions again one by one until you find the buggy one and report it, else
3. Open the Troubleshooting Information via Firebug Button > Help > Troubleshooting Information, click Open Containing Folder, open `prefs.js` in a text editor, copy all lines containing `extensions.firebug` into a separate text file, reset all options (via Firebug Icon Menu (upper left corner) > Options > Reset All Firebug Options), reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching the created file, else
4. In the profile folder go to firebug/, move the file breakpoints.json (if it doesn't exist, go to step 4) out of that folder, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching your `breakpoints.json` (Attention: breakpoints.json contains the URLs of all breakpoints you set, so make sure there's nothing, that shouldn't be public), else
5. In the profile folder under firebug/ move the file annotations.json (if it doesn't exist, go to step 5) out of that folder, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching your annotations.json (Attention: annotations.json contains the URLs of all pages you enabled Firebug for, so make sure there's nothing, that shouldn't be public)

I also found [this thread](http://fbug.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=57280000000&name=firebug.png&token=-D4idAvnDc2vuaLRKSBqQSzYAVc%3A1343412328245&inline=1), created by someone who seems to have had the same problem as you. He says it works with a new profile. To create a new profile, use [this](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Installing_in_a_clean_profile) guide.